# whenever I try to make a post request in postman i get error "Todo validation failed: task: Path `task` is required"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

this is my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const inputRoutes = require("./routes/input");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Acess-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Acess-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS ,GET ,POST ,PUT,PATCH , DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Acess-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});

app.use("/input", inputRoutes);

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MEAN", { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(result => {
    app.listen(2400);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

this is my routes/input.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const inputController = require("../controller/input");

router.post("/todo", inputController.createTodos);

module.exports = router;
```

this is my controller,input.js

```
const Todo = require("../models/todos");
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator/check");

exports.createTodos = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const error = new Error("validation failed due to incorrect data");
    error.statusCode = 442;
    throw error;
  }

  const task = req.body.task;
  const status = req.body.status;
  console.log(task);
  console.log(status);

  const todo = new Todo({
    task: task,
    status: status
  });
  todo
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(task);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "post created sucessfully",
        post: result
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
};
```

this is my model.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const todoSchema = new Schema(
  {
    task: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    status: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);
```

Comment: What is the request your are sending in Postman? It might be helpful to post a screenshot or summary of your Postman settings.

Comment: i am sending key as "task" and value as "complete backend"

Comment: Do these lines print the correct values? 
`console.log(task); console.log(status);`

Comment: when i replace req.body.task with any static value like any string for example "watch tutorials". then the error is gone and im getting the value of task in console log output as "watch tutorials". Hope this may be of any help!!

Comment: Could you verify you are using JSON, as your API expects? If you accidentally selected form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded it would not parse your data.

Comment: @volcanic no it is giving undefined object for both

Comment: In postman POST request body, first choose raw option, and then choose JSON in the dropdown in the right, and in body use something like this  { "task": "task1" }

Comment: @Fdebijl there is no option of JSON so i set it to none in body section in postman

Comment: Based on the information we have we can deduce some things. Your request is reaching the endpoint and is being handled by your function, so both the url and the request method are correct. Also, bodyParser is in place, so you should be receiving the body if sent correctly. If you set body to none in the request you send no body.

Comment: @SuleymanSah thanks a lot sir it worked can u jst please explain me it in short

Comment: @Shreyas what do you want to learn exacly?

Comment: @SuleymanSah basic cause behind that error

Comment: Because to parse the request body in expressjs, you need to send raw JSON data.

Comment: Also there are a few more problems with the usage of express-validator, I described them in my answer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Got it!! Thankss again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send JSON request in the postman first choosing raw option, and then json in the right dropdown.

Also you seem to use express-validator package, but you don't use it in router.

In the router you can use it like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { check } = require("express-validator");

const inputController = require("../controller/input");

router.post("/todo", [
    check("task")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
  ], inputController.createTodos);

module.exports = router;
```

Also in controller you should import the  `validationResult` from `express-validator`,
and validate the result like this:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

exports.createTodos = (req, res, next) => {

  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  ....
}
```